# How to fix ConcurrentModificationException in this code?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to fix this problem, but in any case I do does not fix. Could someone help me?

```
for(Iterator<Block> iterator = event.blockList().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
{
    Block b = iterator.next();

    if (((RegiaoCuboid) r).contains(b))
        event.blockList().remove(b);
}
```

Comment: Please research before posting to SO.  This exact question with the same problem has been asked and answered many, many times on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I had sought, but had not found.

Comment: How did you search?  Did you google "java fix concurrentmodificationexception" and read the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove using the iterator:

```
iterator.remove();
```

A `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when a collection changes in a manner which invalidates open iterators. In this case you are calling `remove` directly on the collection.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that could do that.

Answer (score -2):

You can't modify a List while iterating over it. I would suggest adding the Blocks you wish to remove to a new List, then iterating over that and removing them from the main one (EDIT: Or, do what the other person said). Additionally, if you're doing what I think you are, I would suggest asking further questions on the Bukkit Forums. This question is more general, but Bukkit-specific questions will be more easily answered by individuals who are familiar with the area.

Comment: False, see other answer.

Comment: Not true, as @Reimeus correctly points out `Iterator` has a remove method.